# How can I implement multiple instances of pagination in Algolia instant search?

Tags: javascript, pagination, algolia

Just as title, how can I place multiple pagination widgets on the same page with [Algolia Instant Search](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#pagination)? Simply put I'd like to have a pagination right at the top of the results and another one at the bottom.

I tried giving as `container` an array via `document.querySelectorAll('.pagination')` instead of a single element, unfortunately it doesn't work returning error in console

> Error: Container must be `string` or `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add multiple instances of the instantsearch.js pagination widget you just need to add it several times to your instantsearch instance:

```
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.pagination({
    container: '#pagination-container-1'
  })
);

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.pagination({
    container: '#pagination-container-2'
  })
);
```

Comment: have you tested with it? I dont think that would work.

Comment: @vvo it's really do. My bad.

Comment: Great! No problem :)